# Questions that have to do with exam tasks

Tags: support

Am I allowed to ask such questions when it comes to the CAE exam, for example? 
How do I come up with a title? 
Do I just say "Help with Reading Part 6 CAE" or "This CAE transformation"... has anyone had experience with posting such questions? Can you give me some tips?

Comment: Such questions me are better asked on our sister site, [ELL.se]. And to ask, simply ignore the fact that it comes from a test, the question is important, not your motivation for asking. Treat it like any other question. Which means title it in a way to make it clear what the *question* is about (not its source). Make sure you’ve tried to answer the question for yourself before asking. Show the research you’ve undertaken in pursuit of finding that answer on your own, and the conclusions you arrived at and rejected, and why you rejected them. If there’s quoted material, use `>`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer - I am glad that I would be allowed to ask reading comprehension questions - I will do my best to word them coherently.

Comment: If the only title you can come up with is the number of question on the exam, your question isn’t specific enough. Think about what is making it difficult to understand the passage and ask about that specifically. If you have multiple questions, they should be posted separately even though they are from the same source. As Dan mentioned, the question is what is important, not where it came from.

Comment: "Help with Reading Part 6 CAE" is a damn sight better than "Which is correct?" "problem with sentence" and "Please check my grammar" titles that we often get around here. If the problem is a phrase, verb or an idiom sometimes just quoting the line and adding a question mark at the end is enough info to go on by.

Comment: I disagree that questions that are CAE level should be migrated automatically to ELL. Simply not true, many a time the answers are difficult to explain clearly, and require a native speaker knowledge. It's not just grammar (Use of English)  at level C1.